# How to render API output via React if the page address calls the API once (i.e., without calling the API from within React)

Tags: reactjs, rest, aws-api-gateway

**Context**: I'm working on a simple React app, the basic functionality of which is to receive data from an API and render it on the front end. My API is an AWS API Gateway REST API with a domain that looks `https://api-id.execute-api.region.amazonaws.com/stage`.

I know how to call the API from within a React page (e.g., as below), and this seems to be the most common method.

However, if I want to use a custom domain for the API, like `api.mysite.com/stage`, it is possible to then render the response *when I visit that page*? For instance, if I owned `https://httpbin.org`, could I set things up so that as soon as I visit `https://httpbin.org/get`, the API response, which currently is just a JSON output, would get injected into my React page and rendered according to my design?

If so:

1. How does React receive that data upon the API call completing?
2. How does this work with React Router? I know you can create a route like, `<Route exact path="/id/:id" element={<Template/>}/>`. If that works for the custom domain approach, then another way to put question 1, just above, is about how to get the data that would be rendered as JSON, upon visiting `api.mysite.com/stage/id` into `<Template>`.

I'm pretty new to this, so may have fundamental misunderstandings.

Below: what seems to be the most common method—calling the API from within React. This makes sense. I'm wondering about how to go about accessing data from React *if I visit `https://api-id.execute-api.region.amazonaws.com/stage`*.

```
async function callAPI() {
    return axios(
      "https://api-id.execute-api.region.amazonaws.com/stage",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        data: {
          id: id,
        },
      }
    )
      .then((response) => {
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error: ", error);
        return null;
      });
  }
```

Comment: (1) Save the returned response value from `callAPI` to some state, (2) render the state to JSX in a React component. Do you need more specific help than this? What have you tried so far? Are you stuck on something? Is there an error rendering? What is the specific problem or issue you have?

Comment: @DrewReese, sorry for the confusion; I'll edit the Q. The code snippet above makes total sense to me. What I'm wondering is how to get access to the data if I simply visit the web address of the API. Say, for example, that I own `example.com` and that I've set up an API at `example.com/v1/id`. I know how to call that API from, say, `example.com/dashboard`, using the snippet above, but I don't know what to do if I want to render that response *when I visit `example.com/v1/id/99019`. How do you get the data into React?

Comment: "How do you get the data into React?" - You save it into state and render what you need from it. I don't know how to make it clearer than that since (a) we don't know what the data is and (b) we don't know what you need to render. Why are you trying to visit your backend API endpoint's URL though? You should visit some page where the frontend app is being hosted/served from, and the app calls that function that makes a request to the backend API like you have there in `callAPI`, and handles the returned response.

Comment: I think that pretty much answers the question, in that it sounds like it's bad practice to be visiting the backend URL. I was assuming that when I visit a site with an address like `https://nycidling.azurewebsites.net/idlingcomplaint/26411ec8-db75-ee11-8179-6045bde520b8`, that the URL represents the backend endpoint—but it sounds like what's actually going on is that when I visit that page, there's a function like `callAPI` that calls whatever the actual endpoint is and then returns it for rendering.

Comment: Yes, something along those lines.